# generating NestJS module in nrwl nx throws unhandled exception error

Tags: nestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to generate a NestJS module from the cli in my Nrwl nx project and am getting an error saying

> An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "module" not found in collection "@nrwl/nest".

I'm trying to generate it with

> ng g @nrwl/nest:module my-new-module-name

is this the proper way to do this in Nrwl or is there something else we should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such schematic
[image]

You can only use that one to generate nestjs module
[image]